# Android Device on Linux

Tags: application-development, android, input, output, pipe

I have a Desktop PC running Ubuntu, I also have an Samsung galaxy Tablet.
I am looking for a solution for the following needs:

1. Connect tablet to PC.
2. Tablet opens up as an application window.
3. Application window outputs sound and video from the tablet.
4. Application window takes keyboard and mouse input from the PC to the tablet.

If something like this does not exist, does it not exist because it is not possible?
What similar solutions can I look at to kick-start the creation of it.

Comment: In short, you mean some kind of "Remote Desktop Client" on Ubuntu and "Remote Desktop Server" on Android?

Comment: Those terms are opaque to me. I wrote what the application should be able to do, and you know what "Remote Desktop Client" and "Remote Desktop Server" is and what it can or can not do. You should be in a better position to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) that satisfy all your requirements. Just follow the [Linux’s instructions](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/doc/linux.md).

On Ubuntu 22.04, if you also want the audio from the android device, you need to install the latest version of scrcpy. And your android device must be version 11 or more.

Comment: That looks great. Thanks a lot.